# Is placing error messages inside code blocks bad for SEO?

Tags: discussion, seo

Quite often, we search for an error message to find out what has gone wrong.

Do answers/questions containing error messages in plain text vs in code formatting affect our ability to find such answers/questions via Google search?

Comment: Have you ever had trouble searching Stack Overflow for text that appears in code blocks before? I never have. Works flawlessly for me, as long as I use Google's site search, instead of the lousy built-in search.

Comment: Error messages should never be in plaintext. It looks ugly and is always edited to be in code blocks.

Comment: @ΛRYΛN Not uncommon to see them in block quotes

Comment: @charlietfl it is preferred for the error message to be in a code block inside of a blockquote

Comment: I didn’t even consider block quotes when asking this question. But for completeness it would be good to know the seo implications for all three (plain text, code formatting, block quotes)

Comment: @ΛRYΛN `[citation needed]` - a block quote that just contains a simple code block seems pointless, and IMO doesn't look good.

Comment: @jonrsharpe perhaps, but my point isn't really about aesthetics, it was that it is something being quoted so it should be in a blockquote, and also in a code block since it relates to code. For example, terminal/console outputs usually include a reference to code and are in a monospace font

Comment: @stevec why do you think there would be SEO implications to *any* of them?

Comment: @jonrsharpe my understanding of how SEO works is that Google's crawlers take into account formatting and spacing, so even if the text is identical, it's arrangement on the page can affect seo. I know little about seo btw, others would know a lot more than I.

Comment: You are letting the tail wag the dog here. You shouldn't be making a decision about how to format posts based on arbitrary (and largely mythical) SEO considerations. Instead, you should be making the decision about how to format your posts based on what is *most readable*.

Comment: To put it another way, then: why do you ask? Have you noticed that when you search for an error message you get only the questions where it appears in code blocks/block quote/both/neither?

Comment: @jonrsharpe not at all. I didn’t ask in response to any problem. I asked so can ensure I’m doing the right thing. It would be inefficient if people couldn’t find something because of a formatting blunder. But it appears to not be an issue

Comment: IIRC, it wasn't unusual (in the Python tag) to see error messages in quoted code blocks 5 or 6 years ago. It made it easier to distinguish them from actual code. Of course, it'd be pretty pointless these days with the new quote block style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, code blocks get indexed just fine.

For example, were you to search for `var onlyInA = a.filter(comparer(b));`, you're very likely to see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21988185/1835379) as a top result.